Bootstrap navbar in blade view | Laravel
so I want to make navbar which can collapse.
Im using bootstrap, and everything works fine, if i send the view to different file, i.e.:
@include('shared.html')

@include('shared.head', ['pageTitle' => 'UsedCarsPL'])

<body>
    @include('shared.navbar')
    @include('shared.card')
    ![there is nothing more in this file]!
</body>

in this scenario, the navbar is collapsing as it should, but when i include the navbar in different way:
@include('shared.html')

@include('shared.head', ['pageTitle' => 'Moje samochody | UsedCarsPL'])
@include('shared.navbar')
<body>
    
    <div class="mt-3" style="width:98%">
        <h3 class="text-center">Twoje samochody</h3>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
              [...][...][...]
              [...][...][...]

The navbar collapse is not working. Why?
Ive tried to move the include into body, but still nothing chages.
Thanks for any help!
